# WhereIn limit in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app and I'm trying to show all of the posts in the feed page of the people the current user is following.
It's working well, but my problem is the WhereIn limit.. How can I evade this limitation inside a FutureBuilder?

here is the code:

```
buildFeed() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: storiesRef
          .where('uid', whereIn: widget.userIds)
          .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
          .get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return loading();
        }
        final stories = snapshot.data.docs;
        List<StoryTickets> tickets = [];
        for (var story in stories) {
          List<String> categories = List.from(story.data()['categories']);
          StoryTickets ticket = StoryTickets(
            displayName: story.data()['displayName'],
            categories: categories,
            storyId: story.data()['sid'],
            commentId: story.data()['cid'],
            ownerId: story.data()['uid'],
            rating: story.data()['rating'].toString(), //TODO: maybe delete
            storyPhoto: story.data()['storyPhoto'],
            timestamp: story.data()['timeStamp'],
            title: story.data()['title'],
          );
          tickets.add(ticket);
        }
        return ListView(
          children: tickets,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```